# Can't post to view

Tags: python, django, python-2.7

I'm creating a django app. I have a view and i want it to support both get and post methods. Get is working fine but post is not working for some reason.

My view:

```
class NewCustomer(View):
    def get(self,request):
        c = {}
        c.update(csrf(request))
        return render_to_response("Customer/NewCustomer.html",c)
    def post(self,request):
        c = Customer
        c.Name = request.POST.get("name", "")
        c.Surname = request.POST.get("surname", "")
        c.Email = request.POST.get("Email", "")
        c.PhoneNumber = request.POST.get("PhoneNumber", "")
        c.Address = request.POST.get("Address", "")
        c.SendEmail = request.POST.get("SendEmail", "")
        c.SendSms = request.POST.get("SendSms", "")

        Customer.objects.CreateCustomer(c)
```

Url conf:

```
url(r'^Customers/New',login_required(NewCustomer.as_view()),name="NewCustomer"),
```

Template is just a form with few inputs and a submit button. When i click button, parameters are added to url and it's becoming something like

`/Customers/New?Name=s&Surname=b` etc

What is the problem here?

Comment: Since you didn't post the template we can only guess, but did you put `method="POST"` in the form tag?

Comment: We are wondering about the problem too. At least `c = Customer` does not look too right.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala I'm a learner but since i can't post my form, i can't test that line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your `<form>` element does not specify the method correctly; i.e. it should say

```
<form ... method="post">
```

In the absence of `method="post"` the form will default to `GET` method; and its symptoms will be that all the arguments end up in the URL after `?`

---

Also, your view probably ought to have `c = Customer()`, other things I cannot know based on this information yet.